# Tomcat Remote Deployment

Tags: tomcat7

I want to deploy a WAR from my local windows box to a remote tomcat machine
I am using the following command from Postman

http://10.248.9.104:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/greeting1&war=file:///C:/Users/jagaran.das/Documents/work/AIP/Automation/workspace/gs-rest-service-master/initial/target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war

Also I have tried lot of options.
My main requirement is to control deployment to 100 tomcat server from a central location. I was thinking of using tomcat manager remote deployment way but I am not able to do. Please help
Tomcat Version is Tomcat 7.0.78

Comment: so, what is it stopping you from doing so?

Comment: When I fire the following command in postman, only empty directory is getting created in tomcat webapp and nothing is getting copied